# Xamarin unable to to get file location issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, media

I am building on first app in visual studio. It requires camera.

I am using xamarin cross platform and visual studio 17.

I am using Xamarin media plugin.

I have 2 options in my app. Take picture and Select picture from gallery.

Select picture from gallery works fine.

When I click tak Picture button, it throws an error .

"System.ArgumentException: Unable to get file location. This most likely means that the file provider information is not set in your Android Manifest file. Please check documentation on how to set this up in your project."

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ns6u.png)

Not sure how to fix this.

Here is my code.

**NewPhotoPage.XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Photos.NewPhotoPage">

        <StackLayout Margin="10,10,10,0">
        <Entry x:Name="jobnoentry" Placeholder="Job No"></Entry>
        <Entry x:Name="applicationletterentry" Placeholder="Application Letter"></Entry>
        <Entry x:Name="signnoentry" Placeholder="Sign No"></Entry>
        <Entry x:Name="typeentry" Placeholder="Type"></Entry>

        <Button x:Name="TakePictureButton"
                    Clicked="TakePictureButton_Clicked"
                    Text="Take Picture">

        </Button>

        <Button x:FieldModifier="uploadPictureButton"
                    Clicked="UploadPictureButton_Clicked"
                    Text="Pick a Photo">

        </Button>

        <Image x:Name="Image1" HeightRequest="240"></Image>



            <Button Text="Save"
                Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
        </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**NewPhotoPage.XAML.CS**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Plugin.Media;


namespace Photos
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class NewPhotoPage : ContentPage
    {
        public NewPhotoPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Photo photo = new Photo()
            {
                Jobno =jobnoentry.Text,
                Applicationletter = applicationletterentry.Text,
                Signno = signnoentry.Text,
                Type = typeentry.Text
            };

            using (SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
            {
                conn.CreateTable<Photo>();
                var numberofrows = conn.Insert(photo);

                if(numberofrows > 0)
                  DisplayAlert("Success", "Photos successfully inserted", "Great");
                else
                    DisplayAlert("Failure", "Photos failed to be inserted ", "Try again");
            }
        }

        private async void TakePictureButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
               await  DisplayAlert("No Camera", "No camera available", "OK");
                return;
            }



var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                SaveToAlbum = true,
                Name = "test.jpg"
            });

            if (file == null)
                return;

            Image1.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => file.GetStream());


        }

        private async void UploadPictureButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("No Upload","Picking photo is not supported","Ok");
                return;
            }

            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
            if (file == null)
                return;
            Image1.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => file.GetStream());




        }

    }
}
```

**MainActivity.CS**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Support.V4.Content;
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace Photos.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "Photos", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            int requestPermissions=1;
            string cameraPermission = Android.Manifest.Permission.Camera;
            if (!(ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, cameraPermission) == (int)Permission.Granted))
            {
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { cameraPermission, }, requestPermissions);
            }
            string fileName = "photos_db.sqlite";
            string fileLocation = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string full_path = Path.Combine(fileLocation, fileName);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App(full_path));
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.Photos" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:label="Photos.Android"></application>
</manifest>
```

Can anyone notice anything wrong in my code. Not sure what is causing the file location not found error.

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#android-file-provider-setup

Comment: I tired this. Still same error comes up

Comment: I got it working, Thanks Jason

Answer (score 1):

This error is from the **Media Plugin**

Try to replace in your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.Photos" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:label="Photos.Android">
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
                  android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
                  android:exported="false"
                  android:grantUriPermissions="true">

            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                   android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Make sure you have a file inside the **xml folder**, called **file_paths.xml** with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
  <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
</paths>
```

And also in your Android MainActivity.CS put:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Support.V4.Content;
using Plugin.Media;
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace Photos.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "Photos", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            int requestPermissions=1;
            string cameraPermission = Android.Manifest.Permission.Camera;

            if (!(ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, cameraPermission) == (int)Permission.Granted))
            {
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { cameraPermission, }, requestPermissions);
            }

            string fileName = "photos_db.sqlite";
            string fileLocation = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string full_path = Path.Combine(fileLocation, fileName);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App(full_path));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
 var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    Directory = "MyDirectory",
                    Name = "myphoto",
                    SaveToAlbum = false
                });
```

file.path will give you the path if you set a custom directory. file.AlbumPath with give you the path if you save to album.